# PLAINTEXT signature method for Oauth?

Tags: java, security, oauth

I am trying to use OAuth1.0 + PLAINTEXT signature method for my requests . In OAuth configuration i have this :

```
SIGNATURE_METHOD=PLAINTEXT
```

I want to rely on HTTPS, but i got an
    Unsupported signature method error from Oauth

How can i use PLAINTEXT with OAuth?

Comment: OAuth with which service or you have setup your own OAuth system.?

Comment: I have a service that rely on Oauth for client app authentication and authorization.